# can tauri open the terminal with a default command

Tags: svelte, desktop, tauri

Im trying to make a [tauri](https://tauri.app/) desktop app open a terminal with a default command. Then its up to the user to press enter/return after opening the terminal.

is that possible?

example command

```
$ curl -XGET test.domain -ou test.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Tauri can open the terminal with a default command or shell API.

This example I used in a Nextjs/Tauri app, in a Rust function that is exposed to the Tauri frontend using the #[tauri::command] attribute. Here's an example:

```rust
#[tauri::command]
fn open_terminal(container: String) {
    let command = format!("docker exec -it {} bash", &container);
    std::process::Command::new("osascript")
        .arg("-e")
        .arg(format!(
            "tell app \"Terminal\" to activate do script \"{}\"",
            command
        ))
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
}
```

In this example, open_terminal is a function that takes a container name or ID as an argument, and opens a Terminal window that runs the docker exec -it {} bash command in the specified container. The #[tauri::command] attribute exposes this function to the Tauri frontend, so it can be called from JavaScript or TypeScript code using the invoke function from @tauri-apps/api/tauri.

Here's the full code

```rust
#[tauri::command]
fn open_terminal(container: String) {
    #[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
    {
        Command::new("cmd")
            .args(["/k", "docker exec -it", &container, "bash"])
            .spawn()
            .unwrap();
    }

    #[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
    {
        Command::new("gnome-terminal")
            .args(["--", "docker exec -it", &container, "bash"])
            .spawn()
            .unwrap();
    }

    #[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
    {
        let command = format!("docker exec -it {} bash", &container);
        Command::new("osascript")
            .arg("-e")
            .arg(format!(
                "tell app \"Terminal\" to activate do script \"{}\"",
                command
            ))
            .spawn()
            .unwrap();
    }
}
```

and on your front-end JS you can call it using invoke:

```
await invoke('open_terminal', { container: container });
```